# Error in ng-repeat list: Token '$invalid' is unexpected

Tags: angularjs

below my error :

Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '$invalid' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 28 of the expression [{'has-error': myForm.am1-0.$invalid}] starting at [$invalid}].

```
<div class="row nopadding" ng-repeat="worker in workers">
<div class="col-md-3 nopadding"><h5>{{worker.name}}</h5></div>
<div class="col-md-1 nopadding" ng-repeat="schedule in worker.schedules">
  <div class="row nopadding">
    <div class="col-md-6 nopadding" ng-class="{'has-error': myForm.am1-{{$index}}.$invalid}"><input class="form-control nopadding" type="text" name="am1-{{$index}}" ng-pattern="/(?:[01]\d|2[0123]):(?:[012345]\d)/" ng-model="schedule.am1"
   placeholder="HH:mm" required /></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 nopadding"><input class="form-control nopadding" type="text" name="am2-{{$index}}" ng-pattern="/(?:[01]\d|2[0123]):(?:[012345]\d)/" ng-model="schedule.am2"
   placeholder="HH:mm" required /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row nopadding">
    <div class="col-md-6 nopadding"><input class="form-control nopadding" type="text" name="pm1-{{$index}}" ng-pattern="/(?:[01]\d|2[0123]):(?:[012345]\d)/" ng-model="schedule.pm1"
   placeholder="HH:mm" required /></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 nopadding"><input class="form-control nopadding" type="text" name="pm2-{{$index}}" ng-pattern="/(?:[01]\d|2[0123]):(?:[012345]\d)/" ng-model="schedule.pm2"
   placeholder="HH:mm" required /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row nopadding">
    <div class="col-md-6 nopadding"><input class="form-control nopadding" type="text" name="pm2-{{$index}}" ng-pattern="/(?:[01]\d|2[0123]):(?:[012345]\d)/" ng-model="schedule.total"
   placeholder="HH:mm" required /></div>
   <div class="col-md-6 nopadding" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1 nopadding">40</div>
<div class="col-md-1 nopadding">aaaaa</div>
```

Any idea ??

Thx a lot

Comment: remove the `{{ }}` around the `$index` for a start. Angular already knows you are referring to the scope. `myForm.am1-$index.$invalid`. For the finale, you need to write a function to evaluate this, rather than how you are doing it. So `{ 'has-class': calculate($index) }`

Comment: Hi Isherwood, thank you for your reply, I'll test.